# Switch statement error?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax, switch-statement

I've been editing a script I made to turn a menu icon blue when it is clicked.
The original script had 8 if statements. This worked perfectly, but when I changed the if statements to a switch, it stopped working. I've triple checked it for syntax errors, typos etc, but the menu icons remain grey!

Can anyone give me an explanation?

```
window.onload = function() {

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navico'), function(el) { 
        el.addEventListener('click', imageButtonClickHandler); 
    });


    function imageButtonClickHandler() 
    {  

        switch(this.id) 
        {
           case(this.id.match("aboutnav")):

                grey();
                $('#abouttitle').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#a').css('color', 'blue');
            break;

           case(this.id.match("routenav")):

                grey();
                $('#routetitle').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#b').css('color', 'blue');

            break;

           case(this.id.match("enternav")):

                grey();
                $('#entertitle').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#c').css('color', 'blue');

            break;

           case(this.id.match("racedaynav")): 

                grey();
                $('#racedaytitle').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#d').css('color', 'blue');

            break;

           case(this.id.match("gallerynav")):

                grey();
                $('#e').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#gallerytitle').css('color', 'blue');

            break;

           case(this.id.match("newsnav")):

                grey();
                $('#f').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#newstitle').css('color', 'blue');

            break;

           case(this.id.match("resultsnav")): 

                grey();
                $('#g').css('color' , 'blue');
                $('#resultstitle').css('color', 'blue');

            break;

           case(this.id.match("contactnav")): 

                grey();
                $('#contacttitle').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#h').css('color', 'blue');
            break;

            }
        }
    }

};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know what's the problem but think of using common classes instead of IDs. You can probably reduce that code _a lot_ and make it clearer.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work either. thanks anyway though!

Comment: change "case(this.id.match('...')):" to "case ...:"

Comment: When would a string match an Array or `null`?

Comment: "switch(myArray[...])"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change **this.id.match("something")** into **case "something"** if you are looking for the exact ID values. If you are trying to apply regular expressions to match parts of the string, I think you cannot use switch.

What the switch is doing in your case: for each **case**, it calls the match method and decides if the result of the function (array or null) is equal to your string. This never happens of course.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for exact ID's but it's still not working! Maybe I'll just use the IF statements instead!

Comment: I'd say the quotes have to stay. Which ones would you remove?

Comment: @Gyandeep here is my if statement code http://jsfiddle.net/AdamMartin121/n5uGA/1/

Comment: if(this.id.match("routenav")) -> case "routenav":

Comment: That didn't work before, but somehow it's working now! hah! Thanks @honza_p ! thanks to everyone for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Working example for your problem.
[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/D2nxH/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="aboutnav" class="navico">Click 1</div>
<div id="routenav" class="navico">Click 2</div>
<div id="enternav" class="navico">Click 3</div>
<div id="racedaynav" class="navico">Click 4</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.navico'), function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', imageButtonClickHandler);
    });


    function imageButtonClickHandler() {
        switch (this.id) {
            case "aboutnav":

                $('#aboutnav').css('color', 'blue');
                $('#a').css('color', 'blue');
                break;

            case "routenav":

                //grey();
                $('#routenav').css('color', 'red');
                $('#b').css('color', 'blue');

                break;

            case "enternav":

                //grey();
                $('#enternav').css('color', 'yellow');
                $('#c').css('color', 'blue');

                break;

            case "racedaynav":

                //grey();
                $('#racedaynav').css('color', 'orange');
                $('#d').css('color', 'blue');

                break;
        }

    }
});
```